# How do you populate values from a child popup window to the parent window?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have input fields i would like to populate from a pop up window with table records. When i click on the select button to populate the records, I only get the first record. Even if i select the last record.

I have two separate files. File A and File B. File A activates a popup window of File B. File A

```
 <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="munit">
        <span class="input-group-addon success" onclick="myFunction()"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></span>
    </div>
<input type="text" id="managementu" readonly="readonly" />
<input type="text" id="department" readonly="readonly" />
<input type="text" id="division" readonly="readonly" />
```

File B.

```
 <table class="table">
                       <thead>
                             <tr>
                      <th>Management Unit</th>
                      <th>Department</th>
                      <th>Division</th>
                      <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody id="myTable">
                   <?php foreach ($records as $row){?>
                    <tr>
                      <td><?php echo $rows['Description']; ?></td>
                      <td><input type="text" id="dept" value="<?php echo $rows['Department_Description']; ?>"></td>
                      <td><input type="text" id="divi" value="<?php echo $rows['Division_Description']; ?>"/></td>
                      <td><input type="text" id="reg" value="<?php echo $rows['Region_Description']; ?>"/></td>
                      <td><input type="text" id="dist" value="<?php echo $rows['District_Description']; ?>"/></td>
                      <td><button onclick="copyFunc<?php echo $rows['Code']; ?>()" >Select</button></td>
                    </tr><?php }?>



                <script>
                function copyFunc() {
                   if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed) {
                            var division = window.opener.document.getElementById("division");
                            division.value = document.getElementById("divi").value;

                                 var department = window.opener.document.getElementById("department");
                            department.value = document.getElementById("dept").value;

                            var region = window.opener.document.getElementById("region");
                            region.value = document.getElementById("reg").value;

                            var district = window.opener.document.getElementById("district");
                            district.value = document.getElementById("dist").value;
                        }
                    window.close();
                }
                </script>

                <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
                    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
                    $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
                      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
                    });
                  });
                });
                </script>

                 </tbody>
                </table>
                </body>
                </html>
```

Comment: What “records” are you talking about? Where/how are you “selecting the last record”, when all you got there are some text input fields and a click button?

Comment: @04fs I have values in a table in File B. i want to pass those value to File A. The records are pulled from the **database** using php foreach.

Comment: And where is that foreach loop …? Presumably you are creating duplicate IDs here, which will of course make to your attempts to access elements by ID to go wrong.

Comment: @04fs i have added the foreach loop. sorry i did not indicate that earlier. i only want to be able to post values from the child window to the parent window no matter which row i select from the list/loop

Comment: Well, step 1 is still, fix your IDs. IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document. Or leave out the IDs completely, and find some other way of identifying and locating elements, for example based on a class name and/or position in the DOM.

Comment: I copied the code from somewhere and i modified it to suit my task. But its ONLY working for the first item on the list. Am lost from here. Pls help

Comment: _“But its ONLY working for the first item on the list”_ - again: Due to duplicate IDs. You need to either modify this so that you get unique IDs (and then duplicate the JS code multiple times, if you still want to use IDs to access the fields), or find a different way of accessing them in the first place. I already made a suggestion in that regard, but I am not going to fix your “found” code for you. If you don’t know what other ways besides an ID there are to access elements, then this is the point where you should start doing some additional research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to either modify this so that you get unique IDs (and then duplicate the JS code multiple times, if you still want to use IDs to access the fields),